# Unable to call a function inside Main()

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

i am a starter currently working on a personal project to develop a small application on Python 2 using Tkinter. However, i am facing problem with calling a function that i created. 
*1.* Knowing that Tkinter on Python is event-based, there for i created a button to upload a particular file and then store the values in the file to a List variable. 
*2.* After which, i then use another button to try and call the print function to print values inside the values stored in the List variable.

Hope someone can help me out.

```
def uploadFile():
   openFile = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("",".csv"),("All 
                 files", "*.*")))

   with open(openFile) as file:
     reader = csv.reader(file)
     xUF = [row for row in reader]
   return xUF

def printUF():
   for row in xUF:
       print row
       count=0
       if count>5:
          break
       count += 1

def main():
   l1=tk.Label(root,text="Upload File")
   l1.pack()
   l1.place(x=55,y=170)
   #buttons/placements for GUI
   b1=tk.Button(root,text="Browse", command=uploadFile)
   b1.pack()
   b1.place(x=100,y=200)

   b2=tk.Button(root,text="Print", command=printUF())
   b2.pack()


   root.title("HELLO")
   root.geometry("500x500")
   root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: You didn't really state your problem or the error you are getting.

Comment: `xUF` is a local variable inside `uploadFile()` - it simply does not exist outside of that function.  Returning it from the function doesn't change anything, since it's Tkinter itself that's calling the button's command function, and it doesn't do anything with the return value.

Comment: I did delcare xUF right at the top as an empty list. I thought if i return xUF in the function if will return a value to what i declared right on top with the same variable name?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parenthesis around row

```
def printUF():
   for row in xUF:
    print (row) <---
   count=0
   if count>5:
      break
   count += 1
```

Comment: Notice the 2.7 tag.

Comment: Also notice that xUF doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know what your error is. But I suspect it is this:

You are passing `command=printUF()` to the `Button` class when I think you want just `command=printUF` because `Button` probably wants a function to call when it's hit. As you have it, you're passing the result of `printUF` instead of the function itself to `Button`. The line should look like this:

```
b2=tk.Button(root,text="Print", command=printUF)
```